# Java setting two variables randomly and then setting a third

Tags: java, random

I am trying to figure out how to randomly assign two separate ints as variables. How to choose between them randomly makes sense (`r.nextInt(02)`), but I can not seem to find anything on how to assign one **versus** the other. I'm also trying to assign a third variable based on the sum of the first two, which I think I understand `int c = (int a + b)`. But how do you set the third randomly each time? So that it could either be A, B or C?

Working on a game idea but I'm also constrained by the requirements that I've been given by one of the guys that I'm working under (who isn't available).

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Will do going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the 3 `int`  A, B, C to an array and randomly selecting an index.

```
int[] numbers = new int[3];
numbers[0] = a;
numbers[1] = b;
numbers[2] = c;

int index = rand.nextInt(3);
int yourNumber = numbers[index];
```

Comment: Thank you. I've done several searches (including on this site) and believe that I know what you're speaking of, though I don't want to post bad code.  Would it be possible for you to give me a quick example?

Comment: @WilliamRobinsonIII I have updated my answer to include an example of selecting a random index.

Comment: Brilliant! that is what I had come to in several spots. Your help is greatly appreciated! Cheers.